# Sencha cmd sever error: Aliased resource:

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

With random files I am getting this error from the Sencha cmd Server:

```
[WRN] Aliased resource: file:/C:/Users/hs/Documents/Dev/App/touchApps/touchApps/app/store/ListStore.js~=file:/C:/Users/hs/Documents/Dev/App/touchApps/touchApps/app/store/ListStore.js
```

I also get this error from other random files.

Sencha Cmd v5.1.0.26

Sencha touch 2.4

Any ideas why? (How can I fix this?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this thread: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287420-sencha-web-can-t-serve-ext-from-outside-workspace-tree%28-%29

It looks like you load the same file twice. Double check your workspace (.sencha/workspace/sencha.cfg) points to correct directory.

And make sure that your project space config (.sencah/app/sencha.cfg) doesn't point to the same directory.

Also, check what Loader's path in your app.js.

Comment: You can create an empty workspace and project and take a look. The main thing to check is that you don't point to the same directory twice.

I'm not sure but I'll try to create an example lately today and reproduce your issue.